# Windows key being sent unintentially

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I'm using Microsoft Remote Desktop Beta (8.2.23) to access a Windows 7 (Enterprise edition) workstation via a VPN.

On two separate occasions, when I press <kbd>e</kbd>, Explorer opens (displaying the drives and network locations); when I press <kbd>l</kbd>, the workstation locks.

It would seem that the Windows key is being sent, but I'm not doing so intentionally.  How do I get it to stop?

Ending the session doesn't fix the behavior, nor does restarting RDC.

The behavior also occurs with Microsoft Remote Desktop for OS X (8.0.33).

Comment: I've seen this problem a number of times. It behaves like the key is being held down when it isn't. I've seen it happen not only for the Windows Key, but also the CTRL, ALT and SHIFT keys. Usually if you mash the keys a couple times it'll toggle the state of the key enough that it gets unstuck. Unfortunately, I have no idea what causes it.

Comment: As @Mimp says, try "unsticking" the key. More permanent fixes could come in the form of BIOS updates, USB drivers, third-party programs such as AHK interfering, bugs in the beta, etc. This is an unfortunately common issue.

Comment: I'm using Apple's bluetooth keyboard--I've never had a key get stuck (as far as I can recall).  I wonder if this is related to how the CAPS LOCK can get out of sync with the RDC session if you swipe between OS X desktops (and toggle CAPS LOCK).

Answer (score 0):

If the situation occurs, I've found that pressing the <kbd>command</kbd> key twice resolves the problem.